# Error, return type required in method, but unclear what I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, methods

Very new at programming and I am trying to make a simple program to parse out a date. Check the following relevant code. The error message is "invalid method declaration, return type required." But did I not specify my return type as a String?

```
System.out.println("Enter the date in the following format, MM/DD/YYYY");
    Date = in.nextLine();

    Month = Date.substring(0,2);
    int M = Integer.parseInt(Month);

    Month = getMonth(M);
    System.out.println("The current month is " + Month);

}

public static String (int M)
{
    String Months;
    switch (M)
    {
        case 1:
            Month = "January";
            break;
        case 2:
            Month = "Feburary";
            break;
        case 3:
            Month = "March";
            break;
        case 4:
            Month = "April";
            break;
        case 5:
            Month = "May";
            break;
        case 6:
            Month = "June";
            break;
        case 7:
            Month = "July";
            break;
        case 8:
            Month = "August";
            break;
        case 9:
            Month = "September";
            break;
        case 10:
            Month = "October";
            break;
        case 11:
            Month = "November";
            break;
        case 12:
            Month = "December";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Out of bounds");
            break;
    }

    return Months;

}
```

Comment: Is it `Months` or `Month`?

Comment: `Months` or `Month`. You seem to have played yourself with your bad variable naming. In your method you try to return the never initialized `Months` while setting the value of `Month` inside the switch.

Comment: You used public static String(...) You didn't give the method a name. It should be something like "public static String thisIsAStaticMethod(..."

Comment: give your function a good name like `getMonthInStringFormat`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to give your function a name, for example:

```
public static String getMonth(int M)
```

Comment: oh my gosh. DOH. Thank you